# Customizer add query to preview URL

Tags: jquery, javascript, theme-customizer

In some part of our customizer we are redirecting users to some specific pages.

```
var url = 'https://test.com/specific-page'; 
api.previewer.previewUrl.set( url );
```

We want to pass a custom query along with URL but it's not working as expected. We tried following codes.

Code 1: (not working at all)

```
_.extend( api.previewer.query, { custom_query: 123 } )
api.previewer.previewUrl.set( getFrontendPreviewUrl() );
```

Code 2: (it works but after several reloads, it adds several ? to url)

```
api.previewer.previewUrl.set( api.previewer.previewUrl()  + '?custom_query=' + 123);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if the preview URL already contains your custom_query before adding it?

Something like:

```
var currentURL = api.previewer.previewUrl();

if (strpos(currentURL, 'custom_query') === false) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```